# How to remove Hive table bucketing

Tags: hive, hiveql, partitioning, hiveddl

I mistakenly executed the following `ALTER` statement with table `stocks`:

```
ALTER TABLE stocks
CLUSTERED BY (exchange, symbol)
INTO 48 BUCKETS;
```

How to undo this command?

Comment: Did you try creating a new table like `CREATE TABLE new_table as SELECT * FROM your_bucketed_table` then drop bucketed_table and rename the new_table

Comment: you cannot `undo alter`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If table is managed, then make it external:

```
ALTER TABLE stocks SET TBLPROPERTIES('EXTERNAL'='TRUE');
```

Describe table and note it's location, serde properties and check it is EXTERNAL:

```
describe formatted stocks;
```

Then drop table and create again specifying location, data will remain for EXTERNAL table:

```
   DROP TABLE stocks; 

    CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE stocks(
            columns definition)
        STORED AS TEXTFILE --use the same DDL 
        location '/table_location_path'; --use the same path from describe table
```

Alternatively you can create table with another name pointing to the same location, check it works, make first table EXTERNAL, drop it, rename second table using

`ALTER TABLE tablename RENAME TO stocks`.